# Prevent Path from closing even when end is at start point

Tags: android, path, android-canvas, android-custom-view

Today I ran through a small problem, that is when I start a path and draw an arc from and to the starting point , the path gets closed and hence `PathMeasure`starts giving me wrong data (at least according to what I need) when I need to split the arc to 6 parts and extract 6 points. To see what I mean check this

`path.arcTo(...360f)` gives blank

`path.arcTo(...359.99f)` gives somewhat near but it is still "mathematically" inaccurate 
[image]

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it out by being a bit hacky to in `arcTo` as follows :

[image]